# Can't handle clicks on ScrollBar of Horizontal ScrollView

Tags: android

I had a Grid Layout inside a Horizontal Scroll View, I'm Trying to Implement a Custom Scroll bar for the Scroll View, So far i'm Able to customize the UI of scroll bar [thumb and seekbar] also set visibility permanent. But problem is i'm stuck at handling events on scroll bar of scrollview. Eg. If user clicks on scroll bar in between the ScrollView should scroll to 50% and so on..like click on 1st qurater scroll view should scroll by 25%.

It's pretty simple if i made my own seekbar and bind it to scroll view, also it provides me methods of it's own and click events and can create objects. But i want to do it using ScrollView's slider. How do i handle scroll view's scrollbar clicks, i can create object of ScrollView class. But How will it controll seekbar?? I do not have onseekbarchangelistner for Horizontall scroll view neither it return any achild view or scrollbar view. also it's seekbar not clickable.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@drawable/scrollbar_horizontal_thumb"
        android:scrollbarTrackHorizontal="@drawable/scrollbar_horizontal_track"
        android:visibility="visible" 
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">

        <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnCount="18"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:rowCount="1" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Hi"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your code...jayant

Answer (score 1):

Sorry For Posting this Answer too late:

What is to be done is : Extend a Horizontal Scroll view and override a method onScrollChanged and u get two coordinates x1 and x2. just pass x1 which is real time value indicates how much disance on x axis has been scrolled , to your seekbar setProgress(x1) method. Make sure u set seebar's max value first [setMax()] which is equal to the max scrollable length of scrollView.

```
public class mHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView{
    private float   progress =  0.0f;
    private SeekBar mSeekBar = null;
    private MyActivityClass  mObj    = null;
    private float xMax       =  0.0f;



    public mHorizontalScrollView(Context context, SeekBar sBar) 
    {
        super(context);
        mObj            =   (MyActivityClass) context; //or just use a Static reference
        mSeekBar        =   sBar;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int x, int y, int oldX, int oldY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int myX         =   x;
        if(xMax == 0)
        {
         xMax = mObj.getMaxScrollWidth(); //Choose Your own Scrollable width or length
         mSeekBar.setMax(Math.round(xMax));
        }

         mSeekBar.setProgress(myX); 
         super.onScrollChanged(x, y, oldX, oldY);
    }

}
```

It Worked flawlessly. Now to Implement it reverse Scroll on scroll bar and HorizontallScroll View Should scroll in a proper Syncwith seekbar:

Use Below code in main Activity class :

```
    seek_bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {

            int currScrollPosX  =   progress;
            mHSCV.scrollTo(progress , 0);
           // mHSCV is object of mHorizontalScrollView Class

    });
}
```

Regards.